# I think I fixed a deleted question -- should it be reopened?

Tags: discussion

I had [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24709071/would-jit-compiling-a-macro-language-produce-a-performance-gain) closed as "Unclear what you're asking" and then deleted. I edited the question and believe that it is now fixed.

Did I fix the question, and did I follow the proper procedure for fixing a deleted question?

For < 10K users:

[image]

Comment: Possibly a screenshot for less than 10K users?

Comment: And if you clicked the `Undelete` button to vote to undelete and the `Reopen` button to vote to reopen, then you've done all that you can do.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the question, as well as the discussion in it, which I still think is relevant.

Comment: I would still vote to close with the latest language, so I cannot vote to reopen.  It is an open-ended question.  Suggestion:  attempt to create a compiler for a macro language, and when you get stuck, ask a real question.

Comment: BTW TikZ has quite a few applications common with MATLAB, and MATLAB does get JIT compiled.  But MATLAB isn't really the same sort of a language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't see it as fixed.  It still reads to be too broad, with too many answers and too much subjectivity.

Let's assume that it's not deleted.  If one were to attempt to answer the question, the answer would fall into two distinct categories:  yes, that's been attempted, or no, that's not been attempted.  Of those two categories, they spider out into subjectivity and rhetoric (i.e. "It's been attempted, but the performance gains using XYZ JIT optimization were only X% better than if we had let it be," or "It's never been attempted because it's difficult to introduce a JIT to XYZ platform.")

It doesn't feel like it'd have any good, concrete answers.

Comment: "No" is not a possible answer to a question "Has anyone ever XYZed?".  It might be correct, but no mere mortal can ever know.  We can only infer from a lack of positive answers.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't actually changed the question.

Besides that, your question is in the title.  It's not bad for the title to be a question, but the body should elaborate on exactly what you're looking for, and present an answerable question.  Background information by itself does not a question make.